# Reducing duplicates in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello Stack Overflow community! I'm having some trouble thinking of a way to eliminate duplicate customers in my query. Instead of the report coming up with the same customer fifteen times, I'm trying to list it once only, and in Germany. I've pasted my code below, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
select distinct s.CompanyName 'Company Name', 'Supplier' 'Partner Type', 
s.ContactName 'Contact Name', s.Address, s.City,
s.Country, s.PostalCode 'Postal Code', s.Phone
from Suppliers s 
inner join Products p 
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
inner join OrderDetails od 
on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
inner join Orders o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
where (s.Country = 'Germany')

Union

Select distinct c.CompanyName 'Company Name', 'Customer' 'Partner Type', 
c.ContactName 'Contact Name', c.Address, C.City,
c.Country, c.PostalCode 'Postal Code', s.Phone
from Suppliers s 
inner join Products p 
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
inner join OrderDetails od 
on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
inner join Orders o 
on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
inner join Customers c 
on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where (c.Country = 'Germany')
```

Comment: please update you question add a proper data sample and the expected  result ( looking to your code you should not obtain duplicated )

Comment: That's a very strange `SELECT` statement there with aliases like that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the customers had multiple phone numbers, I removed the phone numbers and this solved the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong table for Phone (s.Phone instead of c.Phone) in your second query part.